# (Generalized) Cantor set is uncountable

Tags: general-topology, cardinals, alternative-proof, cantor-set

The standard Cantor set formed by recursively removing the middle one-thirds, on the interval $[0, 1]$ can be shown to be equal to the uncountable set of the base-3 numbers between $0$ and $1$ with the digits after the decimal point being $0$ or $2$.

But, suppose we remove $1/\pi$-ths. Can we deduce from the above that the Cantor set obtained this way will still be uncountable?

---

I am aware of the fact (not versed in the [proof](https://mathcs.org/analysis/reals/topo/proofs/pfctuncb.html); it's too complicated yet) that perfect sets are uncountable, and I can show that these generalized Cantor sets removing $r$-th fraction in each step ($0 < r < 1$) are perfect.

I want to know if something like the "decimal representation" proof is possible here, or if the uncountability can be deduced from that in the $r = 1/3$ case.

Comment: With a bit of thought you can get an explicit (if **really** messy) bijection between your set and the usual Cantor set. HINT: build your bijection in stages.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Are you suggesting the following kind of mapping: For instance, $0.2020...$ in the $1/3$ Cantor set gets mapped to the unique number in the $r$ Cantor set that lies in the following successive intervals: The right interval in the first stage, the left interval in the second stage, the right interval in the third stage, and so on with $2$ being the "right" and $0$ standing for the "left".